# c++ nested conditional operator loop

Tags: c++, loops, nested, conditional-statements, operator-keyword

I'm curious about how c++ handles this nested conditional operator. I'm half sure that I understand how this works, but I'm curious, **could anyone explain through a diagram how the loop would execute the nested conditional operator**.

For example would the loop execute through the first expression of each conditional operator for each instance?

Also is this nested conditional operator structured as:

(i < 2) ? x[i] : y;

!i ? y : x[1];

I guess I'm just very curious about the nature of this. Please don't answer unless you are capable of giving me a thorough adequate explanation of how the loop executes this conditional operator.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

{
const char x[2] [20] = {" Cloud "," at your service\n"}; 
const char * y = "Strife"; 
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
    cout << (( i < 2)? !i ? x [i] : y : x[1]);

cout << endl << endl << x[0] << endl << x[1] << endl;

cin.get();
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt, spell it out...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    if (i < 2) {
        if (!i) { // technically, this is "if i == 1"
            cout << x[i];
        } else { // and this is "if i == 0"
            cout <<y;
        }
    } else {
        cout << x[1];
    }
}
```

Simply go through the statement.  Everything before a `?` goes in an `if`, then just open a `{` until we see a `:`.

Answer (score 7):

It seems you are asking how an expression like `x ? y ? 1 : 2 : 3` is parsed.

If you think about it there is really only one possibility.  Namely, the `:` furthest to the right *must* bind to the `?` furthest to the left.  Thus the expression parses as:

`x ? (y ? 1 : 2) : 3`

So, if `x` and `y` are `true`, then `1` is returned; if `x` but not `y` is `true`, then `2` is returned; and if `x` is `false`, then `3` is returned.

Sorry to not answer directly in the context of your problem but I felt like it would be easier to follow this way.

Answer (score 1):

The operator is not structured as you write. Maybe it is clearer with parentheses:

```
cout << ((i < 2) ? (!i ? x [i] : y) : x[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some good analysis already of what the conditional means.  Just wanted to contribute a couple suggestions:

- consider writing or reordering such expressions such that the `?` and `:` alternate,
- consider breaking them on to multiple lines with indentation reflecting their processing.

Either or both of these should make it easier to keep track of what they do.

Consider:

```
i < 2 ? !i ? x[i] : y : x[1]   # somewhat confusing...
```

Just indenting to reveal processing precedence:

```
i < 2      // if               just put ? and : beneath related condition
? !i       // then if
  ? x[i]   //      then
  : y      //      else
: x[1]     // else
```

Or to simplify while keeping one-liner concision, try:

```
i >= 2 ? x[1] : !i ? x[i] : y   # equivalent but simpler to "grok" (see below)
```

Expression ordered to alternate `?` and `:` work like a simple `if` / `else if` / `else if` / `else` chain, so you can process and eliminate possibilities steadily as you work your way through.

```
if (i >= 2)
    (value is) x[1]
else if (!i)
    x[i]
else
    y;
```

I sometimes write alternating conditionals across lines too:

```
std::cout << (i >= 2 ? x[1] :    // "if condition1 then value1 else
              !i ? x[i] :        //  if condition2 then value2 else
              y);                //  value3"
```

...or sometimes (depending on the line lengths and visual complexity) going the whole hog and lining up the `:` beneath `?`...

```
std::cout << (i >= 2
              ? x[1]
              : !i
                ? x[i]
                : y);
```

As with many stylistic aspects of C++ source code, picking a nice layout is a bit of an art - but experimentation is a good way to get a feel for it.